# Biot-Savart magnetic field at point $P$ semi-infinite wire

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have an infinite wire and I would like to know the magnetic field at a point $P$.

$$\vec{dB} = \frac{u_0I}{4\pi R^2} \cdot \vec{dl} \times \hat{r}$$

for a semi-infinite wire as in the image I know $\theta \in[0,90]$, but I'm not sure how to write it mathematically. I know at the end the equation should looks like

$$\vec{B} = \frac{u_0I}{4\pi R}(\sin(90^\circ)+\sin(0^\circ))$$

However, I'm not sure how to get it from this properly.
$$\vec{B} = \frac{u_0I}{4\pi R^2} \cdot \int\vec{dl} \times \hat{r}$$

[image]